# change date languge

Tags: linux, date, language

I'm working on Reh Hat linux server,I want to change date language to "French".
when I run the command `date` I get `Thu Aug 25 13:30:25 CEST 2022` as you can see, the language used is English how to change it to French ?

When I run `locale`  I get

```
LANG=fr_FR.iso88591
LC_CTYPE="fr_FR.iso88591"
LC_NUMERIC="fr_FR.iso88591"
LC_TIME="fr_FR.iso88591"
LC_COLLATE="fr_FR.iso88591"
LC_MONETARY="fr_FR.iso88591"
LC_MESSAGES="fr_FR.iso88591"
LC_PAPER="fr_FR.iso88591"
LC_NAME="fr_FR.iso88591"
LC_ADDRESS="fr_FR.iso88591"
LC_TELEPHONE="fr_FR.iso88591"
LC_MEASUREMENT="fr_FR.iso88591"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="fr_FR.iso88591"
LC_ALL=
```

Comment: what are result of `which date` , `whereis date` and `command -v date` ? (I got *almost* same environnement LC_var, that is `LC_TIME=fr_FR.UTF-8` and get my date in french)

Comment: which date return /usr/bin/date

Comment: Have you done `# dracut --force ` and rebooted?

Comment: why this command dracut --force

Comment: Is the French langpack installed? `yum list installed langpacks*
` Have you considered using `UTF-8` instead of the dated `iso88591`?